# Run Django background task on heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

So, I have a Django Project which has a background task for a method to run.
I made following adjustments to procfile
Initially

```
web: python manage.py collectstatic --no-input; gunicorn project.wsgi --log-file - --log-level debug
```

Now

```
web: python manage.py collectstatic --no-input; gunicorn project.wsgi --log-file - --log-level debug
worker: python manage.py process_tasks
```

Inspite of adding worker, when I deploy my project on heroku it does not run the background task. The background task gets created and can be seen registered in django admin but does not run. I hoped after reading various articles (one of them being https://medium.com/@201651034/background-tasks-in-django-and-heroku-58ac91bc881c) adding worker: python mnanage.py process_tasks would do the job but it didn't.

If I execute in my heroku cli: heroku run python manage.py process_tasks it only runs on the data which was initially present in database and not on any new data that I add after deployment.

Note: python manage.py process_tasks is what I use to get the background task to run on my local server.

So, if anyone could help me in running the background task after deployment on heroku.

Comment: Same issue. In the heroku log, I see `2020-10-11T12:10:06.319405+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/mydb/background_task/task/" host=my-app.herokuapp.com request_id=2ca2c0fa-0927-4549-af31-69905364f130 fwd="67.249.51.226" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=149ms status=200 bytes=29123 protocol=http`, but record in Django Admin never updates. Attempts is always 0.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Procfile` seems right, you need to scale your worker dyno using `heroku scale worker=1` from heroku CLI or you can also scale your worker dyno from heroku dashboard.

For scaling worker dyno through browser:-

1. Visit `https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/<your-app-name>/resources`
2. Edit your worker dyno and scale it from there confirm your changes

In CLI use command `heroku logs -t -p worker` to see status and logs for worker dyno